# Javascript and this error. Depending on how function called

Tags: javascript, this

So this is tough.  When calling a method directly, this refers to the containing object while when calling from string conversion, this refers to "window" (i believe, i could still be completely wrong).

Could anyone explain this to me?

What will happen is a javascript error AFTER the first alert statement (that means direct call worked fine with how `_this` was defined)

```
/**
 *  converts a string to a function
 */
function stStringToFunction(string) {
    var fnList = string.split(".");
    var currentFn = window;
    var nextFn;
    while(currentFn !== undefined && (nextFn = fnList.shift())) {
        currentFn = currentFn[nextFn];  
    } 
    return currentFn;
}

//An example library
UnderstandingThis.ui.Component1 = {
    performTask1: function(options) {
        var settings = {
                opt1: true,
                opt2: false
            },
            _this = this;

        $.extend(settings, options);

        _this._PrivateTask1(settings);
    },
    _PrivateTask1: function(settings) {
        //Some sweet stuff here!
        alert("Private task1: " + settings.from);
    }
}
UnderstandingThis.ui.Component1.performTask1({from: "direct"});
stStringToFunction("UnderstandingThis.ui.Component1.performTask1")({from: "string-to-function"});
```

---

My lack of explanation required an edit:  2/21/2012 9:56 AM (Montana)

So the problem is that the faux library (`UnderstandingThis.ui.Component1`) contains a function that uses `_this` (which is set to `this`) and works fine when doing a direct method call.  By that i mean in javascript calling `UnderstandingThis.ui.Component1.performTask1()`.  But if i call this same task via a string conversion `stStringToFunction("UnderstandingThis.ui.Component1.performTask1")()` `_this` refers to `window`.  But to me that does not make sense.  I have only been doing javascript for 1.5 years and these little nuances (coming from Java/C#) are difficult to understand.

Comment: What error? there are too much undefined in the question. **humor++**

Comment: Sorry, let me define the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial assertion:

> When calling a method directly, this refers to the containing object

is not really true.  The `this` pseudo-variable is bound based on the object reference used to get to the function (if any).  If you instantiate a function as a property value of some object, and then call it by reference via that object property, then yes, `this` is bound to that object.  However, if you copy the function as a value to a property of *another* object, then a call via that other object will have that object as `this` (it's always a "Who's on first?" issue when discussing this topic :-).

In any case, you can use `.call()` or `.apply()` to force the `this` value to be whatever you want, regardless of how you get to the function.  The bottom line is that in JavaScript there is never any inherent relationship between a function and any particular object. The binding of `this` is determined at every function call.

Comment: You provided some great information.  I understand where i was wrong.  You and quentin have same answers, yours is just more generalized.

Answer (score 4):

If you call:

```
foo.bar()
```

Then inside `bar`, `this` is `foo`.

If you:

```
var baz = { bar: foo.bar };
baz.bar();
```

Then inside `bar`, `this` is `baz`.

If you were to:

```
var bar = foo.bar;
bar();
```

Then inside `bar`, `this` is `window` (because it is the default object).

Your function extracts the function from its context and then calls it (so `this` is `window`).

Comment: An excellent answer, but maybe not to this question, cuz I couldn't get the "question part" in it.

Comment: This is very close to the question.  This is a great explanation. My string to function conversion basically does the "bar()" function call...

Comment: The only reason why i did not accept yours is that yours was a very practical example, but did not lead me to a deeper understanding of `this`.  I understand where i went wrong in my example, but @Pointy explained how `this` is generated with more depth.  I did give you a vote up, your answer was good.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is exactly what you thought, this in the second call refers to the window. Here is a possible workaround, but personally i'd do things in a different way. Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/LsH7V/

```
/**
 *  converts a string to a function
 */
function stStringToFunction(string) {
    var fnList = string.split(".");
    var currentFn = window;
    var nextFn;
    while(currentFn !== undefined && (nextFn = fnList.shift())) {
        currentFn = currentFn[nextFn];  
    }
    return currentFn;
}

//An example library
UnderstandingThis = {};
UnderstandingThis.ui = {};
UnderstandingThis.ui.Component1 = {

    performTask1: function(options) {
        var settings = {
                opt1: true,
                opt2: false
            };
        if(typeof _this === 'undefined'){    
            _this = this;
            console.log(this);
        }

        $.extend(settings, options);

        _this._PrivateTask1(settings);
    },
    _PrivateTask1: function(settings) {
        //Some sweet stuff here!
        alert("Private task1: " + settings.from);
    }
}
UnderstandingThis.ui.Component1.performTask1({from: "direct"});
stStringToFunction("UnderstandingThis.ui.Component1.performTask1")({from: "string-to-function"});
```

Comment: could you please show me how you do this.  Code is code, there is no "right" way of doing things. (I am not justifying crappy code, but good code can be done several ways)